# Two OutputStream's instead of one?

Tags: java, outputstream

I am dealing with a commerical Java API that exposes only the following logging configuration:

```
cplex.setOut(OutputStream arg0);
```

I would like to have logging to two streams: a file and the console.
Is it possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Write your own OutputStream implementation which delegates calls to the `write` methods to two wrapped OutputStreams, one for the console and one for the file.

Comment: I redirected the logging to log4j from there and it works fine.

Answer (score 11):

i believe it is.

I would user the [apache commons io lib](http://commons.apache.org/io/).

For example

```
FileOutputStream fos = ...;
TeeOutputStream brancher = TeeOutputStream(fos, System.out);
cplex.setOut(brancher);
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use a [`TeeOutputStream`](http://commons.apache.org/io/api-release/org/apache/commons/io/output/TeeOutputStream.html) from the [Apache Commons IO library](http://commons.apache.org/io/).

Answer (score 0):

Easy:

```
cplex.setOut(new OutputStream() {

    public void write(int b) throws IOException {
        outputStream1.write(b);
        outputStream2.write(b);
    }
});
```